# Unix - How to check if firewall is blocking mailx functionality?

Tags: bash, unix, sharepoint, connection, firewall

I am attempting to write a script that utilizes the `mailx` command. The script is supposed to send files as attachments to a SharePoint directory.

I use the following command to encode and send the files:

```
uuencode $fullPath ${file} | mailx -m -s "Outage Report" ${testEmail}
```

The script work correctly when I use my personal email as the outbound email address. The files are sent to Outlook as attachments to emails.

I can also send files (as attachments) to the SharePoint from Outlook. The files are uploaded to the appropriate directory.

However, when trying to send files directly from the script to the SharePoint there is a disconnect and no files are uploaded.

**Q:** How can I check the status of the outgoing mail connection when attempting to send directly to SharePoint via the script? That is, how can I diagnose what is blocking my connection (firewall, ..)?

I have been playing around with the `netstat` command, but I am unsure how to utilize it properly to check the issues that I am having with my script.

**Edit:**

Mail.log lists the following error in the stat field:

```
stat=Transient parse error -- message queued for future delivery
```

The mail queue has the following note connected to mail that has not been sent:

```
(host map: lookup (domain): deferred)
```

Comment: Have you tried -d or -v switches?

Comment: If you're referring to `netstat` I have tried the `-v` option but I'm not exactly sure how to decipher the information it's printing. It does not look overly helpful. Should I run the `-d` option prior to  `netstat -v` ?@Buddy

Comment: No, I think @Buddy was referring to the `-d`/`-v` switches on `mailx` to turn on debugging and verbose mode.  On another topic, have you tried sending plain test emails without file attachments?  Do those make it to the SharePoint destination?

Comment: Are there any error messages? (should be on the server you are sending from OR on the receiving end...)

Comment: @dg99 - yes, meant `mailx`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I am using an HP-UX machine and `-v` is not a supported option for `mailx`. The resulting output when using the `-d` option is not particularly helpful. It does state the location of `dead.letter` but I do not have access. I have attempted sending a plain email with no attachment, but it does not make it to the SharePoint. @Buddy @dg99

Comment: @Dale_Reagan I am not receiving any error messages directly to the console. It is possible error messages are being logged, but I am not sure where I would find these logs.

Comment: Hmm, HP-UX system - I will guess /var/log folder; Also, I will guess that you will not be able to review the logs without privileged access.  Do you have Zsh on this system?  Also, try sending a simple message to yourself from this system, i.e. mails -s "Test message" you@you < /dev/null; if that works then probably not a firewall issue...

Comment: There is no log folder within the var directory. Zsh is not on the system unfortunately. Messages without attachments also do not make it to the SharePoint @Dale_Reagan

Comment: Googling suggests:  /var/adm/syslog/mail.log  - did you try a simple mail message?

Comment: @Dale_Reagan I did try sending a simple mail message, but it also did not get sent. I was able to find the log file. The lines referring to emails I attempted to send have the following message in the `stat` field: `stat=Transient parse error -- message queued for future delivery`.